# VB.NET MessageBox with markup in forms

Tags: vb.net, markup, messagebox

I want to show a MessageBox in a VB.NET application that has special markup for its text. More specifically, I want to display an unordered list. I tried doing it by wrapping the text in HTML tags (which Java Swing supports for example, if I'm not mistaken) and working with `<ul>` and `<li>`. This did not work. I can't find anything on the net about it either...

The textbox is used in a normal Windows forms application.

Does anyone know how to do it without creating a completely custom messagebox class?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3782979/284240

Comment: @TimSchmelter not really, but thanks

Comment: Is it asp.net client side messagebox? Would you to put in some code?

Comment: @IvanH Oh yes sorry, it's a Windows forms application.

Comment: This isn't possible, the native Windows message box dialog has no support for this.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you post that as an answer, so I can accept, and for further reference for anyone who happens to find this? Thanks.

Comment: Meh, I don't like "you can't do that" answers much.  They are very rarely appreciated.  You can write your own post and accept it.

Comment: @HansPassant I can understand that, but it's still an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) says, this is not possible with the default `MessageBox` in VB.NET.